# Upgrade from FreeBSD 10.1 to 10.2 fails because of incorrect hash

Tags: freebsd

```
$ sudo freebsd-update upgrade -r 10.2
Fetching metadata signature for 10.1-RELEASE from update.FreeBSD.org... done.
Fetching metadata index... done.
Fetching 1 metadata patches. done.
Applying metadata patches... done.
Fetching 1 metadata files... done.
Inspecting system... done.

The following components of FreeBSD seem to be installed:
kernel/generic src/src world/base world/lib32

The following components of FreeBSD do not seem to be installed:
world/doc world/games

Does this look reasonable (y/n)? y

Fetching metadata signature for 10.2-RELEASE from update.FreeBSD.org... done.
Fetching metadata index... done.
Fetching 1 metadata patches. done.
Applying metadata patches... done.
Fetching 1 metadata files... done.
Inspecting system... done.
Fetching files from 10.1-RELEASE for merging... done.
Preparing to download files... done.
Fetching 1 patches. done.
Applying patches... done.
Fetching 4626 files... 5f019a418777cb657afa2135ec50532d4a61f8c6b1373e4e4f6b173f3aa98741 has incorrect hash.
```

I retried it several times, but it keeps failing. In the error message, the hash itself differs. The number of files to be fetched also decreases.

**What do you recommend to solve the update problem?**

Is it possible to purge the caches? Or should I use another server (instead of the default one: update.FreeBSD.org)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "corrupt" file is stored in `/var/db/freebsd-update/`  The files are named for their hash.  You may be able to proceed simply by deleting the file that was downloaded incorrectly, so that your next run if `freebsd-update` downloads it again.

```
sudo rm /var/db/freebsd-update/5f019a418777cb657afa2135ec50532d4a61f8c6b1373e4e4f6b173f3aa98741.gz
```

I have always found that a re-download was sufficient. In my experience, it's the download process, not the file at the mirror, which is the problem.

That said, if the file *is* in fact corrupt on the mirror, then downloading the same file won't help, and you should try selecting a different mirror as Mark suggested.

Comment: Thanks, after some retries, it managed to download all files. The path was "/var/db/freebsd-update/<HASH>.gz" on my system.

Comment: Ah, yes, on my system too -- overzealous copy-and-paste. I've fixed the answer. Thanks!  :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm experiencing the same behavior.  This has happened a few times in the past year, and it appears to have typically been due to errors in updating the mirrors.

I retried a couple times and hit a good mirror, you could try forcing it to use particular ones and see how that goes.  I believe it was either update5 or update6 that worked for me.

Alternately, you can wait until they get a chance to fix it.  I reported the issue, so hopefully it'll be addressed "soonish".

Comment: I had similar problem. `update5.freebsd.org` works for me. I have configured `ServerName` parameter in `/etc/freebsd-update.conf`.